# How to change the FoV?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

How do you change your field of view? I do not see it in the options.

In ME1, it appears there was a console command you could use: http://www.tweakguides.com/ME_5.html

> If you want to adjust the Field of View, see the FOV console command

I'm not sure about ME3 though.

Would FoV changes affect multiplayer too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone has posted an excellent guide on how to do this on the [steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2584112)

Summarized here:

Edit your bioinput.ini file and put these commands under the bindings section (bioinput.ini > sfxgame > sfxgamemodebase > bindings ):

> ( Name="NumPadZero", Command="FOV 32" )
>    ( Name="NumPadOne", Command="FOV 0" )
>    ( Name="NumPadTwo", Command="FOV 75" )
>    ( Name="NumPadThree", Command="FOV 80" )
>    ( Name="NumPadFour", Command="FOV 85" )
>    ( Name="NumPadFive", Command="FOV 90" )
>    ( Name="NumPadSix", Command="FOV 95" )
>    ( Name="NumPadSeven", Command="FOV 100" )
>    ( Name="NumPadEight", Command="FOV 105" )
>    ( Name="NumPadNine", Command="FOV 110" )

You can add as many as you want but these will allow you to adjust FOV in game.

Comment: Who would set their FOV to 0?

Comment: @MBraedley a scientist.

Comment: Also related: [Will the FOV fix get me banned from multiplayer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54602/3062)

Comment: Related: [How do I edit Coalesced.bin?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54867/3062)

Comment: @MBraedley FOV 0 switches to the default FOV, for cinematic camera.

Comment: @MBraedley The `FOV` command is a hard global override. You have to use `FOV 0` during cutscenes which otherwise will look bad because the override forces them to have FOV that they were not designed for.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a better solution https://hamstergene.github.io/posts/2012-11-27-fixing-mass-effect-fov/

The global `FOV` console command messes up cutscenes, taking cover, a lot of things. What **really** needs to be changed is the `SFXGame.SFXCameraMode.FOV` property, for example:

```
( Name="NumPadZero", Command="set SFXGame.SFXCameraMode FOV 100" )
```

It does what you expect nicely without any side effects. It only affects the default mode (running and shooting) and does not touch conversations or cinematics. This is the only binding you need; you won't need `FOV 0` and `FOV 32` anymore. Don't forget to revert back `Shared_Aim` if you changed it.